# How to use result from Angular 6 subscribe() method outside?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, get

I am trying to create a config.json file with just a few urls and read the data in a Service.

.../.../assets/config.json

```
{
    "registration" : "localhost:4200/registration"
    "login" : "localhost:4200/login"
}
```

../services/config.service.ts

```
export class ConfigService {
  result;
  configUrl = '../../assets/config.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl).subscribe((data) => { this.result = data });
  }
}
```

In the specific `login.service.ts` and `registration.service.ts` I call the `getConfig()` to handle the specific urls. The problem is that in this services the return value is undefined but I need the result out of the subscribe/getConfig method.

Now I am watching about 3 hours for a solution but I do get much more confused as more as I read so I would like to ask for help.

I saw solutions with `.map()` method (but I guess this method does not exist anymore), with "Promises", with `export interface` but nothing worked.

example for ../registration.service.ts

```
export class RegistrationService {

  private api_url;

  constructor(private http: HttpClientModule, private cs: ConfigService) {
    this.api_url = this.cs.getConfig();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Config Service:

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl).toPromise();
}
```

Your Registration Service :

```
async exampleMethod() {
  try {
    this.api_url = await this.cs.getConfig();
    console.log(this.api_url);
  } catch(e) {
    throw Error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked thank you. I was a little bit confused because console.log(this.api_url) in another method showed also undefined but I guess it is because of the async work flow. But for the api it works and gets the needed urls. Thank you!

Comment: Np, I suggest You to use .toPromise() and play with async await. It's "smoothie" and there is no point to "subscribe" to a http request. Subscribing to web sockets for example make much more sense.